# Case status icon

Tags: servicecloud

I noticed in this screen that cases have icons related to it and it's a formula field. But where Can I find this icons ? Is a pack or other ?

Thanks

[image: Case icon status]

Comment: geez - that's a 47 minute video -- please excerpt the icon and [edit] your post

Comment: sorry!  post updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These appear to be icons from the SLDS icon set: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility

Look at (under Utility):

- away
- record
- routing_offline
- check (this one is under *Action* icons)

Comment: this icons are available directly on SF or I need to upload it ?

Comment: If you want to use these in a formula field, you'll need to save them from the SLDS library and then upload, I wouldn't reference the lightningdesignsystem URL since it's outside of your control and subject to change. Some instructions on using images in formulas: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327122&type=1